# Add/Delete a row on button-click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a screenshot as shown below:

[image]

The screenshot above belongs to the following code:

```
    <h3 style="text-align:center;margin-top:45px;">Sitting Days</h3>
    <div class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <!-- Date START --> 
        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;"> 
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
            <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date" value="<?php if($data->{" house_sitting_date "}<>''){echo $data->{"house_sitting_date "};}?>">
        </div>
        <!-- Date END -->
        <!-- Yes/No Dropdown START -->
        <div class="yes-no">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4>
            <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no" id="house-yes-no" style="height:24px;">
                <option value="nada" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="nada"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Please choose an option</option>
                <option value="yes" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="yes"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Yes</option>
                <option value="no" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="no"){echo 'selected';} ?>>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Yes/No Dropdown END -->
        <!-- Add new row button START -->
        <div class="add-new-row-button">
            <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="rowAdd()"/>
        </div>
        <!-- Add new row button END -->
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript Code START --> 
    <script>
    function rowAdd() {

     }
    </script>
   <!-- Javascript Code END -->
```

On hitting **save** button, the above form **(as shown in the screenshot)** gets saved in the following JSON file:

```
$output['house_sitting_date']=$_POST['house_sitting_date'];
$output['house_sitting_date_yes_no']=$_POST['house_sitting_date_yes_no'];

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what **JavaScript code I need to add** so that it add another **select of rows**. When I say **Select of Rows**, I meant to say the following. I added an onclick event on input tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change some minor things, but this is the general idea:

```html
<h3 style="text-align:center;margin-top:45px;">Sitting Days</h3>
<div class="add-new-row-button">
    <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="rowAdd()" />
</div>
<div id="rows">
    <div class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
            <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="yes-no">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4>
            <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no" id="house-yes-no" style="height:24px;">
                <option value="nada" selected>Please choose an option</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function rowAdd(event) {
        document.getElementById("rows")
          .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow());
    }
    
    function newRow() {
      return `
        <div id="default-node" class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="yes-no">
                <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no" id="house-yes-no" style="height:24px;">
                    <option value="nada" selected>Please choose an option</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
      `
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The answer looks great. Thanks for the help :). Although, it would like to see few changes. On hitting **Add New Row** button, it should not show **Select Date** and **Yes/No** every-time.

Comment: Ok then... I would like to see what constitutes a "row"... You say you want a new "row" added - what do you mean by "row"? I took "row" to mean the drop downs..

Comment: The row here constitutes **Date** and **Yes/No**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks awesome. That is what I was expecting. I just want one minor change. Lets say there are 3 rows already. If I add one row, 
it deletes the content present in the 3 rows already.

Comment: Can you supply an example? Not sure I follow.

Comment: Lets say in 1st row, I enter **2020-12-20** and **Yes**. On adding a new row, it deletes the content entered in the previous row

Comment: Does it make sense ? or should I give more information ?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean - I have updated my answer.  EDIT: just cleaned up my answer so it doesn't require cloning a node...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will let you know if you need any help.

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866216/how-to-delete-a-complete-row-on-button-click-in-javascript). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: @flash i just answered it for you.

Comment: @flash did you have a chance to take a look at that answer?