# How to delete a complete row on button click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, dom

I have a **html/php code** as shown below. The below **html/php** code is working in a way that on adding rows, we can select date from every row and can save it as well.

Two things need to be done.

1. On clicking **Delete** button, it should remove the value from the **JSON** array because everything is pulled from the **JSON** after saving the form.
2. Also, on clicking **Delete** button it should delete the complete row from the DOM.

Comment: Do you actually have a `rowDelete()` function?  I'm not seeing one.

Comment: @PatrickQ Check the third line of the question.

Comment: All relevant code should be in the body of the question itself.  If you have a `rowDelete()` function, please include it _in_ the question.  If you do not have one, then I'm not really sure what your question here is, because your buttons expects there to be one.

Comment: I have mentioned my question in the **Problem Statement**. On clicking **Remove** button, it should delete a row. We can add **n** number of rows on clicking **+** button and then **Save** it as well.

Comment: The reason why I haven't mentioned in the question because the code would become too messy.

Comment: You can select the row from the button with the `closest` method of the button element. Then you remove the row with `removeChild`, but for this you have to first find the parent of the row you want to remove ... So something like: `const row = event.target.closest(".row"); const rowParent = row.parentElement; rowParent.removeChild(row);`
(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

Answer (score 0):

you should give each added row an id corresponding to its rank:

```
row.id=i.toString();
```

then use the following code to remove the row:

```
var row = document.getElementById(rowrankid);
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

Comment: how does this remove the entry from the json file, though?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a code sample for you using your example that does exactly what you say.

It is using a javascript fetch post request to post to the script you have provided to remove the dom elements and update the json file.

I have changed some of your paths slightly so you will need to change those back (add in the ../feeds/ parent directory)

Once the user has pressed the button the page will reload, showing the updated interface that is loaded from the json file.

There are some improvements that could be made, for example the javascript is not checking to make sure the request was successful before reloading, but as the input is date select it should be ok.

```
<?php

if(file_exists('./ptp-ess_landing_house.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('./ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    if(isset($_POST['requestType']) && in_array($_POST['requestType'], ['remove'])) {

        switch ($_POST['requestType']) {
            case 'remove' :
                    //Unset the values
                    unset($data->row_delete[$_POST['data'] -1]);
                    unset($data->house_sitting_date[$_POST['data'] -1]);

                    //We are reindexing the arrays as we have deleted some rows, note that we are using +1 array indexes
                    $data->row_delete = array_values($data->row_delete);
                    $data->house_sitting_date = array_values($data->house_sitting_date);

                    foreach($data->row_delete as $key=>$value) {
                        $data->row_delete[$key] = strval($key+1);
                    }

                    //Write the file back
                    $fp = fopen('./ptp-ess_landing_house.json', 'w');
                    fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
                    fclose($fp);

                    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    echo 'ok';
                    die;

                break;

            default:
        }

    }
}
?>
<script>
    function rowDelete(row) {
        //Make a request to your entry file (index.php here) to do the removal
        fetch('/index.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({requestType: 'remove', data: row})
        }).then(function(response) {
            location.reload();
            return response;
        });
    }
</script>
<?php if($data) { ?>
    <form method="post">
        <div id="rows" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;"><!-- Big div START -->

            <!-- Remove Button START -->
            <div class="rows-delete">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Delete Rows</h4>
                <?php if (empty($data->row_delete)) { ?>
                    <div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:22.5px;">
                        <button type="button" id="delete" onclick="rowDelete()">Remove</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="row_delete[]" value="1" />
                    </div>
                <?php } else {  ?>
                    <?php  foreach ($data->row_delete as $row_delete){ ?>
                        <div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:22.5px;">
                            <button id="delete" type="button"  onclick="rowDelete(<?php echo $row_delete;?>)">Remove</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="row_delete[]" value="<?php echo $row_delete;?>" />
                        </div>
                    <?php }} ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Remove Button END -->

            <!-- Sitting Date START -->
            <div class="sitting-days">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
                <?php if (empty($data->house_sitting_date)) { ?>
                    <!-- Select Date START -->
                    <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                        <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="">
                    </div>
                <?php } else {  ?>
                    <?php  foreach ($data->house_sitting_date as $date){ ?>
                        <!-- Select Date START -->
                        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                            <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="<?php if($date) {echo $date;}?>">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Select Date END -->
                    <?php }} ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Sitting Date END -->

        </div><!-- Big div END -->
    </form>
<?php } else {
    echo 'Cannot read JSON settings file';
}
?>
```

Comment: @flash did you have a chance to check this yet? I believe it should be the marked answer as it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is known at the front-end (which I think you are implying, since your `rowDelete` is a JS-function), you can pass `this` with the call to `rowDelete`. Then you can traverse the DOM to get to value the corresponding sibling input-field (perhaps something like `this.parentNode.childNodes[1]`).

Once you have that value, you can easily remove it from the corrsponding array in your json:

```
let d = '2020-01-30'
let idx = arr.indexOf(d)   
let newdates = ([...arr.slice(0,idx), ...arr.slice(idx+1)])
data.house_sitting_date = newdates
```

(with some additional index bounds checking, of course).

After that, you can perform a similar DOM traversal to remove the corresponding element from the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Flash, unfortunately, the desing of the code itself is not much professional...  there are separate loops for rows (in php), which instead should be only 1 loop, like (with example simple Javascript binding on click):

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<count($data["house_sitting_date"]); $i++)
{
     echo '<div class="remove"><a id="'.$data["row_delete"][$i].'" onclick="deleteRow(this);">Remove</a></div>';
     echo '<div class="date">....</div>';
     ...
}
?>
<script> function deleteRow(el) { el.remove(); } </script>
```

also, lots of embedded `style=""`.. codes, instead you might use 1 style file.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I know my **for loops** are bit messed up but I will clean the code once my **Delete** button start working.

Comment: Why don't you clean the code first then start adding more stuff? That sounds like a more logical approach to development...

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did in past, and it works perfectly

Prerequisite for this answer to work is each button and input field should be in DIV with unique id and there should be container for all these div in my case its

.

On Add button(if you have one) you need clone node, and paste it under or above the element where it was clicked,

```
    // Create a clone of element with id ddl_1:
    let clone = document.querySelector('#row'+rownumber).cloneNode( true );
    // Append the newly created element on element p 
    document.querySelector('p').appendChild( clone );
```

Then every time you add a new row or delete a row you need to append ids on these row, to do this you would a common class for all these rows in my case I used, rows

```
    function changeids()
    {
     let rows =document.getElementsByClassName('rows');

     for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
     {
       let thisid="row"+i;
       rows[i].setAttribute("id", thisid);

       let thisAddButton = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("add")[0];
       let thisDeleteButton = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("delete")[0];

       let onclickaddfunction = "addrow("+i+")";
       thisAddButton.setAttribute("onclick", onclickaddfunction);

       let onclickDeletefunction = "removerow("+i+")";
       thisDeleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", onclickDeletefunction);

     }
}
```

Then when you remove you need to remove node and call changeids again

```
function removerow(rownumber){

document.getElementById('row'+rownumber).remove();
changeids();
}
```

This would give you whole working idea of add and delete rows, whole code below please ignore my messy code, just did it to give you and idea

```
<p>

  <div id="row1" class="rows">
   <button class="add" onclick="addrow(1)">add</button>
   <button class="delete" onclick="removerow(1)"> remove </button>
   <input type="text">
  </div>
</p>


<script>
function addrow(rownumber)
{
  // Create a clone of element with id ddl_1:
  let clone = document.querySelector('#row'+rownumber).cloneNode( true );

 // Append the newly created element on element p 
 document.querySelector('p').appendChild( clone );

 changeids();

}

function removerow(rownumber)
{
   document.getElementById('row'+rownumber).remove();
   changeids();
}

function changeids()
{
  let rows =document.getElementsByClassName('rows')

  for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
  {
   let thisid="row"+i;
   rows[i].setAttribute("id", thisid);

   let thisAddButton = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("add")[0];
   let thisDeleteButton = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("delete")[0];

   let onclickaddfunction = "addrow("+i+")";
   thisAddButton.setAttribute("onclick", onclickaddfunction);

   let onclickDeletefunction = "removerow("+i+")";
   thisDeleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", onclickDeletefunction);

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and indent your code properly so that it becomes readable.

Comment: @MrUpsidown done, can you remove the negative vote now?

Answer (score -2):

To delete row from dom, you have to specify unique id for main element of row and you can use [ElementObject].remove() method to delete, So everything inside that will be removed.
Also You should simplify and change JSON data, so that it will delete from json also using ajax with using single id(key) as parameter.

Here is the working code:

```
<?php

        if (!empty($_GET)) {
            if (!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
                if(file_exists('ptp-ess_landing_house.json')) {
                    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('ptp-ess_landing_house.json'), true);
                    if (!empty($_GET['row_number'])) {
                        unset($data[$_GET['row_number']]);

                        $fp = fopen('ptp-ess_landing_house.json', 'w');
                        fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
                        fclose($fp);

                        echo 1;
                        exit;
                    }
                }

                echo 0;
                exit;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $output = array();     

            if (!empty($_POST['row_item'])) {
                $output = $_POST['row_item'];
            }

            $fp = fopen('ptp-ess_landing_house.json', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
            fclose($fp);
        }

        $data = array();
        if(file_exists('ptp-ess_landing_house.json')) {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('ptp-ess_landing_house.json'), true);
        }

        ?><form method="post">
            <!-- Add New Row Button START -->
            <div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
                <button type="button" id="addRow" onclick="rowAdd()">+</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Add New Row Button END -->
            <div id="maindiv">
                <div style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="rows-delete" style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px;">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Delete Rows</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sitting-days" style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="choose-options" style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="yes-no-option" style="display:inline-grid;">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Big div START --><?php

                $totalrow = 0;
                foreach ($data AS $key => $row) {
                    ?><div id="row-<?php echo $key; ?>" style="display:flex; justify-content: center; margin-top:20px;"><?php

                        ?><div class="rows-delete" style="text-align:center;">
                            <div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px;">
                                <button type="button" class="delete" onClick="delete_row(this.value)" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">Remove</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="row_item[<?php echo $key; ?>][row_delete]" value="<?php echo $row['row_delete'];?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <!-- Remove Button END -->
                        <!-- This is what I have tried to add a button (END) -->    

                        <!-- Sitting Date START -->
                        <div class="sitting-days" style="text-align:center;">
                            <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                                <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="row_item[<?php echo $key; ?>][house_sitting_date]" value="<?php echo $row['house_sitting_date']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <!-- Sitting Date END -->

                        <!-- YES/NO START --><?php
                        ?><div class="choose-options">
                            <div class="yes-no-option" style="display:inline-grid;">
                                <select name="row_item[<?php echo $key; ?>][house_sitting_date_yes_no]" class="house-yes-no" style="height:24px; ">
                                   <option value="<?php echo $row['house_sitting_date_yes_no']; ?>" <?php if($row['house_sitting_date_yes_no'] == "nada" ) echo "selected";?>>Please choose an option</option>
                                   <option value="<?php echo $row['house_sitting_date_yes_no']; ?>" <?php if($row['house_sitting_date_yes_no'] == "yes" ) echo "selected";?>>Yes</option>
                                   <option value="<?php echo $row['house_sitting_date_yes_no']; ?>" <?php if($row['house_sitting_date_yes_no'] == "no" ) echo "selected";?>>No</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- YES/NO END -->
                    </div><?php

                    if ($key > $totalrow) $totalrow = $key;
                    else $totalrow++;
                }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="totalrow" id="totalrow" value="<?php echo $totalrow; ?>">
            </div>
            <!-- Big div END -->

            <hr />
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </div>

        </form>

        <script>
            function delete_row(row_number) {
                var data = '<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>';
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if (typeof(data[row_number]) != undefined) {
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.open("GET", "index.php?action=delete&row_number=" + row_number);
                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                            var row = document.getElementById('row-'+row_number);
                            row.remove();
                        }
                    }
                    request.send();
                }
                else {
                    var row = document.getElementById('row-'+row_number);
                    row.remove();
                }
            }
            function rowAdd(event) {    
                var totalrow = document.getElementById("totalrow").value;
                totalrow = parseInt(totalrow) + 1;

                document.getElementById("maindiv").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow(totalrow));

                document.getElementById("totalrow").value = totalrow;
            }
            function newRow(row_number) {
                return `<div id="row-` + row_number + `" class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-top:20px;">
                    <div class="rows-delete" style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px;">
                            <button type="button"  class="delete" onClick="delete_row(this.value)" value="` + row_number + `">Remove</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="row_item[` + row_number + `][row_delete]" value="` + row_number + `" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sitting-days" style="text-align:center;">
                        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                            <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="row_item[` + row_number + `][house_sitting_date]" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="choose-options">
                        <div class="yes-no-option" style="display:inline-grid;">
                            <select name="row_item[` + row_number + `][house_sitting_date_yes_no]" class="house-yes-no" style="height:24px; ">
                               <option value="nada">Please choose an option</option>
                               <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                               <option value="no">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
            }


    </script>
```

Comment: just the same as `file_get_contents()` is used to read the file, `file_put_contents()` can be used to update the file (instead of `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`)

Comment: @Tuckbros Yes, I know that file_put_contents() can be used to write into file, But user question was not related to this, I just use his incorrect code and convert into working code which is related to how to delete row from DOM and json.