# How to make the button stay in a row in php/json?

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, dom

As the title suggests, I am unable to make the button stay in a row after saving the form. I am able to add a button in a row through JavaScript.

I have a php code as shown below. The below html/php code is working in a way that on adding rows, we can select date from every row and can save it as well.
**Now I am trying to add a button in a row.** Here is the [script](https://jsfiddle.net/m7aesyqc/1/) **(its entirely JS)** which
I have used in order to add a button (having any text) in a row.

The issue which I am having right now on adding rows is that the button do show up in every single row but after saving the form and coming back, the button disappears from every single row probably **because nothing is getting saved in the JSON**.

**html/php code:**

```
<?php
$output = array();
```

**Problem Statement:**

The issue which I am having right now that I can add as many rows as we want but the button doesn't stay after saving the form. Only rows containing the dates stay on the web-page.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php/javascript code above so that the button stay after saving the form. When I checked the JSON, nothing is getting saved there so probably that can be the reason **why buttons doesn't stay after saving the form**.

**Edit 1:**

In JSON, it is null **{"row_delete":null}** so that's the reason why the button doesn't stay in every row after saving the form.

Comment: row_delete() function in your script is for deleting new_row before save.,and so it  only show up on add_more, and after save it go away. its basically cancel button for add new row

Comment: That function is not needed. I have updated that script.

Comment: rowDelete() function will be used to delete a row. That is another part of the question which I will work later. The issue which I am having right now on adding a row, the **Remove** button do show up in every single row but after saving the form, the remove button disappears from every single row. It failed to stay after saving the form and coming back to the web-page.

Comment: ok,are you sure your json is returning $data->row_delete. has some data?

Comment: @AhmedSunny That's what I figured out just now. It is returning null. In JSON(../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json) it is returning {"row_delete":null} 
That's the reason why **Remove** button doesn't stay after saving the form. I think, I need to make some logic for the remove button to stay after saving the form.

Comment: your delete button doesn't need a special id, it can have the id of the record, and you just need to pass that id to your function and delete that record. you can add a dclassname for delete and call a click event on it. and just get the respective id and send it to server.

Comment: PS it appears you're vulnerable to XSS javascript injection, ```<?php if($date) {echo $date;}?>```  should be ```<?php if($date) {echo htmlentities($date,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED);}?>```

Comment: @hanshenrik Nothing is getting saved in the JSON so that's the reason why nothing is getting pulled from there. 
Javascript is working perfectly fine because of that I am able to add a row. On adding a row, button stays there but after saving the form 
and coming back buttons are no longer present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button was not displaying because you will not get HTML button element value in php request. To get button value, you will have to use extra hidden variable with value

```
<?php

            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $output = array();     

                if (!empty($_POST['house_sitting_date'])) {
                    $output['house_sitting_date'] = $_POST['house_sitting_date'];
                }

                if (!empty($_POST['row_delete'])) {
                    $output['row_delete'] = $_POST['row_delete'];
                }

                $fp = fopen('ptp-ess_landing_house.json', 'w');
                fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
                fclose($fp);
            }

            $data = [];
            if(file_exists('ptp-ess_landing_house.json')) {
                $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
            }

            ?><form method="post">
                <!-- Add New Row Button START -->
                <div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
                    <button type="button" id="addRow" onclick="rowAdd()">+</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Add New Row Button END -->
                <div id="rows" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;"> <!-- Big div START -->

                    <!-- This is what I have tried to add a button (START) -->  
                    <!-- Remove Button START -->
                    <div class="rows-delete" style="text-align:center;">
                        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Delete Rows</h4><?php
                        if (empty($data->row_delete)) {
                            ?><div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                                <button type="button" />Remove</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="row_delete[]" value="1" />
                            </div><?php
                        }
                        else {
                            foreach ($data->row_delete as $row_delete){
                                ?><div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                                    <button type="button">Remove</button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="row_delete[]" value="<?php echo $row_delete;?>" />
                                </div><?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?></div>  

                    <!-- Remove Button END -->
                    <!-- This is what I have tried to add a button (END) -->    

                    <!-- Sitting Date START -->
                    <div class="sitting-days" style="text-align:center;">
                        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4><?php 
                        if (empty($data->house_sitting_date)) {
                            ?><!-- Select Date START -->
                            <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                                <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="">
                            </div><?php 
                        }
                        else {
                            foreach ($data->house_sitting_date as $date){ ?>
                                <!-- Select Date START -->
                                <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                                    <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="<?php if($date) {echo $date;}?>">
                                </div><?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?></div>  
                    <!-- Sitting Date END -->


                </div>
                <!-- Big div END -->

                <hr />
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>

            </form>

            <script>
                function rowAdd(event) {
                        document.getElementById("rows")
                          .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow());
                    }
                    function newRow() {
                var row_delete = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="row_delete[]"]');
                var row_delete_length = row_delete.length + 1;

                return `<div id="default-node" class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <div class="row-delete" style="margin-right:30px;">
                             <button type="button">Remove</button>
                             <input type="hidden" name="row_delete[]" value="` + row_delete_length + `" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                             <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="">
                        </div>
                </div>`;
            }
            </script>
```

Note: Remove raw code is not provided, I think you will be capable enough to do this

Comment: Hey Pradeep, the answer looks good. What is happening right now is in JSON for every single row I am getting the following  **{"row_delete": ["1", "1", "1"]}**

Comment: So this is not what you want? What you were expecting for row_delete?

Comment: I am thinking if we can have unique value for everys button. That button is actually a **Delete** button which will delete a row on clicking it.

Comment: The logic which I am going to apply is on clicking **Delete** button it will remove the value from JSON array and remove the respective row having that **Delete** button.

Comment: At present in JSON, I am getting this {**row_delete":["1","1","1","1","1"]**}

Comment: Please check code again, I have made some changes. Now you will get unique value for row_delete. 
Before this, please delete all data in JSON and than perform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer on this question. I have given the bounty.  I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866216/how-to-delete-a-complete-row-on-button-click-in-javascript/59971473#59971473). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: What I want to achieve now on clicking a **Delete** button it should delete the entire row. I know my for loops are bit messed up but I will clean the code once **Delete** button start working.

Comment: You should simplify and change json in order to do that. Let me give you example

Comment: Completely agree on that. Two things need to be done. On clicking **Delete** button, it should remove the value from the **JSON array** because everything is pulled from the **JSON** after 
saving the form. Also, on clicking **Delete** button it should delete the complete row from the **DOM**.

Comment: I have added answer to your new post. Please check that working code.